# Android - Voice Chat Between 2 or More Android Devices over WIFI

Tags: android, chat, wifi, voice

I want to make an app for voice chat between 2 or more android devices over wifi (local-intranet) can any one direct me in the right direction.

Any good tutorial or working example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hey you are talking about Session Initiation Protocol go to this link you will get some info

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html

https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/develop-ims-sip-client-android-part-2

http://www.voipsupply.com/blog/first-look-sipdroid-open-source-sip-client-for-android-mobile-phones

also see this

https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/develop-ims-sip-client-android-part-3

surely you will get something how to start up with SIP.

Comment: Is voice chat possible without SIP?

Comment: khan that i dont know i just know that audio and video is possible via SIP.

Comment: ok thanks...I'll go through the links. thanks alot.

Comment: `labs.ericsson.com` links are not working....